# Why do I need to quote the table name `5e09c9c09e9ba0cceccb3701` in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

## Context

I encounter a bug in our application related to MySQL table names. Our application generates table names as a 24 hexadecimal digits number (i.e.: `5e09c9c09e9ba0cceccb3701`).

Everything went fine for a while, but suddenly we started to see SQL syntax errors with certain table names. The bug was easy to fix : we needed to protect the table name.

**SQL syntax error :**

```sql
select * from 5e09c9c09e9ba0cceccb3701;
```

**No error :**

```sql
select * from `5e09c9c09e9ba0cceccb3701`;
```

---

## Question

Why table names starting with `5e09` need to be protected ?

I went through the MySQL documentation for reserved words or hexadecimal literal notation, but I cannot find any explanation for the special interpretation of `5e09` in a SQL statement.

And, if anyone knows, what other *special* prefix might also break the syntax of an SQL statement ?

Comment: have you tried another names? something like 5e09c9c09e9ba0cceccb3701k?

Comment: A couple of quotes from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html , 'It is recommended that you do not use names that begin with Me or MeN, where M and N are integers.' ,'Be careful when using MD5() to produce table names because it can produce names in illegal or ambiguous formats'

Comment: You can use this as an reference on offical mysql dev channel  [9.1.4 Hexadecimal Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd guess that 5E09 is parsed as a number (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5E09) and the parser struggles with concatenating this number with the rest of the table name (speculation), since mysql allows table names starting with a number, but requires that it not solely consists of digits.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html, quoting:

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

In other words, all table names starting with [0-9]E[0-9] should show the same behavior.

Just spun up a local mysql instance, the pattern seems to match:

- 5e0x doesn't work
- 5f0x does work
- 5eax *does* work

I'd consider filing this as a bug, albeit a low-priority one :)